# Run cronjob on 2 days per year

Tags: cron

I’m looking to run a cronjob on 2 days every year: 1/4 and 12/6 both at midnight. Is this possible with 1 line or do I have to add 2 lines? I know how to run a cron on a specific day and time and also how to run it so it runs on Jan and Dec 4th and 6th (it running 4 times per year) but not how to specify the 2 days seperately (it running only the 2 times I want).

Comment: The comma operator is used as a value list separator.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator is a value list separator.

From [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru),
“At 12:00 on day-of-month 4 and 6 in January and December.”

```
0 12 4,6 1,12 *
```

Comment: So this cron isn’t run on 1/4, 1/6, 12/4 and 12/6 then? But only on 1/4 and 12/6?

Comment: @vespino For that I believe, you'll have to add two lines.